# Redirecting to another page at the end of a new thread generates an exception

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I have a web page which displays a form.  There is a `<div>` on this form which has Visible = FALSE.  Once the form is populated by the user, and the user clicks a button, the code behind will change the `<div>` to Visible = True and starts a new thread.  This allows the `<div>` to show a spinning wheel and display "please wait..."  The new thread does some processing which takes a few seconds.  After the new thread is finished processing, I need to redirect to another page.  This is the code that starts the new thread:

```
        Session("Finished") = "False"
        If Not continue_button() Then
            ts = New ThreadStart(AddressOf LongRunningProcess)
            th = New Thread(ts)
            th.Start()
            panelWait.Visible = True
        End If
```

And this is the code of LongRunningProcess

```
Protected Sub LongRunningProcess()
    Dim zoho_autoCustNo As Integer = 0

    zoho_autoCustNo = Val(saveDatatoZoho())
    submitpmt(zoho_autoCustNo)
    Session("Finished") = "True"
    Try
        Response.Redirect("new_signup_thank_you.aspx", False)
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
    Response.Redirect("new_signup_thank_you.aspx", False)
End Sub
```

The Response.Redirect that is in LongRunningProcess throws an exception but I do not know how to catch it, ignore the exception, and still execute the Response.Redirect.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Jonathan

Comment: What is the exception then???

Comment: It generates an "HttpException was unhandled" message.  It gets generated on the second Response.Redirect.  When I traced it through Visual Studio, it executes the Try and fails so it executes the code in the Catch (which is no code at all).  Then it exits the Try and fails on the Response.Redirect.

Comment: Remove/comment out the `Try`/`Catch` and give me a more detailed error message please.

Comment: @JonathanSmall, that is not going to work. You have already sent the response to the client, the new thread has no access to it. You should never spin up your own threads in asp.net anyway. Lastly, and this is not a solution, the proper way to redirect is: `Response.Redirect(url, false)
 Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()`

Comment: I took out the Try / Catch and generated the error again.  This is what I copied to my clipboard:  System.Web.HttpException was unhandled
  ErrorCode=-2147467259 HResult=-2147467259
  Message=Response is not available in this context.
  Source=System.Web WebEventCode=0

Comment: @Crowcoder I'm not sure I understand what you mean by the response was already sent to the client.  What I 'm trying to figure out is how to get the new thread to load a new page instead of having the pages' main thread execute the response.redirect.

Comment: @JonathanSmall, you can't do that with a new thread. Asp.net runtime knows what it is doing and it will handle a request/response round trip on one thread. You might want to use ajax techniques to do asynchronous execution or a websocket technology like SignalR. Or just let it all run on the main thread, its not a problem at all (unless you mean really long running).

Comment: @Crowcoder The main thread displays the page and on a button click (which causes a post back) will change the visibility of a <div> from visible=false to visible=true.  Also, the style of this <div> has transparency.  So, on the button click, the <div> will display a spinning wheel and a "please wait..." lable.  Also on the button click, I start the new thread.  When the main thread finishes executing code, the web page is displayed and the longrunningprocess thread is still running.  Once the longrunningprocess code is finished,I assume that thread ends as well.  So how do I redirect?

Comment: @Crowcoder I should also add that this is the first time I have ever tried to write a web application with multiple threads and that I am a completely self-taught .net programmer so my methods may not be the best.

Comment: @JonathanSmall, I think I understand what you are doing but this is not a desktop app, you are dealing with client/server architecture here. Your new thread runs but the httpcontext is lost, it cannot redirect the response because the client already got the page. One easy rule to follow is - don't create threads. [Read this](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html). If your operation is not so long that the request will time out, then just let it run. You can use some javascript on the client to show a spinner while the user waits. Better though to do async ajax.